# How do I get the width of a bar including padding in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have an ordinal scale the width of the bar including the padding.

In this case it returns `rangeBand` returns `29.03`.

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain([0, 1, 2])
    .rangeBands([0, 100], 0.1);
console.log(x.rangeBand());
```

If I have `0` padding it returns `33.33`.

How do I get the width including padding?

Comment: That's the extent of the range divided by the number of bars, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

For d3.js v4, for a bar graph where you defined your x-scale with something like this:

```
var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, n]).padding(0.25).domain( ... )
```

you get the actual width value of a bar+padding with `x.step()` and the width value of padding with `x.padding() * x.step()`

Answer (score -1):

instead of hardcoding pass on the variable.
for example

```
var padding =10;
var width = 100;
var rw = width + padding;
```

so your code will be

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain([0, 1, 2])
    .rangeBands([0, rw ], 0.1);
console.log(x.rangeBand());
```

Comment: The padding is the `0.1` part (the padding between each bar).